# How does the Search operation in iOS Settings work?

Tags: ios, settings, search

If I enter "accelerometer" into the Search bar of Settings in iOS 16.5 on my iPhone X, the results seem to include practically every "Accessibilility" settings page. Are they all matching because they both begin with "acce"?

And if I just type some random characters, I still get quite a few results. I entered "Ljrfbirfj" and got about a hundred matches. A bunch of them are the Acknowledgement screens from various apps' "about" and license screens, but many of them don't seem to follow any kind of pattern.

So what's the searching algorithm that causes garbage to find dozens of matches?